# Can you always create an algebra from a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a group with elements $\{e,g_1,g_2,...\}$ can you always turn this into an algebra like:

$X=a+b g_1 + c g_2 + d g_3+...$

where the coefficients are real.

Also I note in some cases the group has elements that act like $-1$ or $(-1)^{1/n}$. For example if $g^2=e$ and some other conditions it behave like $-1$.

(Like in the quaternion group.) Thus even though the quaternion group has 8 members, it can be made into an algebra with 4 variables.

In what cases can we make an algebra with less elements than the group like this? For example by making the coefficients complex numbers or quaternion numbers?

(Conversely, I suppose, can an algebra always be turned into a group?)

Comment: Given a group you can always construct an algebra called the group algebra. I don't know what it would mean to have an element that acts like $(-1)^{1/n}$ in a group. Is this a multiplicative or additive group? How would we interpret this in the context of a single binary group operation?

Comment: Well you would have elements $g_k=(-1)^{k/n}$ so that $g_k \otimes g_q = g_{k+q \mod n}$ and so forth. And also all the other elements would be $h_{p,k}$ so that $g_k \otimes h_{p,q} = h_{p, k+q \mod n}$ with $e=g_0$.

Comment: So you're asking when can a group $G$ embed in the multiplicative group of an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of dimension less than $|G|$?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, I guess so. And also $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{H}$